# Nested layout in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have two panel in my application, CustomerPanel and AdminPanel. I want to use general layout for both panels and call CustomerPanel layout and AdminPanel layout inside general layout.
what is the best way of nested layout in zf2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ZF1 this kind of Feature was called `ActionHelper`. In ZF2 we no longer have this helper available. However there is a much cleaner and better solution available.

Michael Gallego has written an article about it:

- [How to replace the "Action" helper in ZF 2 (and make great widgetized content)](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/10/06/how-to-replace-the-action-helper-in-zf-2-and-make-great-widgetized-content/)

There's two different approaches and usually. For smaller Widgets, i.e. rendering an AdminMenu, you are probably best of with a `ViewHelper`. The nature of a `ViewHelper` is to be small and simple, so once code starts to get more complex and more logic has to be added to your Widget, go with the `forward()`-Method, as explained inside the article.